# Finding a unique sequence in dataset that do not exits in other

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering if there is a known algorithm/solution for the following problem.

I have a set of 10000 files coming from family X and another 10000 files coming from family Y.
By family I mean that the files are closely related to each other (in terms of code sharing).

I am looking to discover a unique sequence (DNA) that exists in all (or most) the files in family X BUT do not exits in family Y.

How can I extract such a DNA?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly I believe this is the solution:

1. create a class that represents said DNA.
2. fill one set with the DNAs from the first file and count their prevalence.
3. fill another set with the DNAs from the second file.
4. subtract the second set from the first set to get all the DNAs that exist in the first set of files and don't exist in the second set of files.
5. the most prevalent DNA from the DNAs received in step 4 is the one you're looking for.

note: in your DNA class (or in your sets, depeneding on what language you're using) remember to take care of equality and hashing.